# How to ignore a specific warning in PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, warnings, pydev

How do I ignore a specific warning in Eclipse?

I am doing ZetCode's [PyQt4 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/) [LPTHW](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) style (yes, I'm using PyDev), and adding helpful comments so I can use it as a reference. Eclipse is bugging me about an unused variable. (It *is* being used, because the initialization function automatically runs the code. Just to be clear.)

I don't want to turn it off for the whole file, because that is actually handy in most situations. I just want to ignore that warning.

Answer (score 1):

For suppressing warnings on a specific line, your only option is to add a comment such as `#@UnusedVariable` to the line:

```py
def foo():
    x = 5 # @UnusedVariable
    return 10
```

To suppress a different type of warning, see the list of suppression string constants in the [PyDev source code](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev.ast/src/org/python/pydev/ast/analysis/IAnalysisPreferences.java):

```java
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_IMPORT = "@UnusedImport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_WILD_IMPORT = "@UnusedWildImport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_VARIABLE = "@UnusedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE = "@UndefinedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_DUPLICATED_SIGNATURE = "@DuplicatedSignature";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_REIMPORT = "@Reimport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNRESOLVED_IMPORT = "@UnresolvedImport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_NO_SELF = "@NoSelf";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNDEFINED_IMPORT_VARIABLE = "@UndefinedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_PARAMETER = "@UnusedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_NO_EFFECT_STMT = "@NoEffect";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_INDENTATION_PROBLEM = "@IndentOk";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_ASSIGNMENT_TO_BUILT_IN_SYMBOL = "@ReservedAssignment";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_PEP8 = "@IgnorePep8";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_ARGUMENTS_MISATCH = "@ArgumentMismatch";
```

For example:

```py
def get_answer(format='string'): # @ReservedAssignment
    answer = 42.0
    if format == 'string':
        return str(answer)
    elif format == 'int':
        return int(answer)
    else:
        return answer
```